# Перестали работать breakpoint в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Запускаю студию в режиме Debug! Почему-то перестали работать breakpoint в Visual Studio Enterprise 2015?

Comment: например потому что вы их отключили, или не попадаете на строчку где установлен брейкпоинт, или запускаете в релизе

Comment: -строчка точно выполняется. Вижу результат, а остановки нет!!

Comment: как я их мог отключить?

Comment: например выбрали:disable breakpoint

Comment: Может студия глюканула и отладчик срывается...

Comment: какая версия студии, апдейты?

Comment: breakpoint - enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, потому что ты скопировал проект в другое место, а часть ссылок ведут к старому коду или бинарникам. Однажды сам такое довольно долго искал.

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! грохнул папки bin и obj пересобрал ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!!!